# Assistance with an issue in my codes return values

Tags: java, format, rate

First I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction so no outright answers please. 
My code is running correctly or so I thought, whenever I run the code with test values I am getting
a crazy value for the monthly payment amount.

I am using these values as given to me:
Amount; $500,000.00
Interest: 5.6%
Years: 30

I am getting 2,000,000 or so as an answer any help would be greatly appreciated!

Primarily the part below.

```
    public static double getInterestAmount(Scanner sc, double loanAmt, double interestRate, int years) {
        int months = years * 12;

        double monthlyPayment = loanAmt * interestRate / (1 - 1/Math.pow(1 + interestRate, months));
        return monthlyPayment;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a tip: since the specific question is about how the monthly payment amounts are wonky, you'd probably have gotten answers faster if you pruned out all of the code to get user inputs and just posted code that uses a specific hard-coded value and demonstrates the problem. It makes spotting the issue faster for everyone involved, and in particular would make it clear if the problem actually lay in the input reading code.

Comment: One thing that you may see after a while; code dumps can be received very poorly (with close votes and downvotes). Doing pruning steps like the above beforehand will help with how it's received, and is just a good debugging practice in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You didn't divide the interest rate, which is entered as a percentage, by `100` to convert it to a decimal.  Divide it by `100`.
2. You need to divided the interest rate by `12` to get a monthly rate in the formula.

**EDIT** (you said no outright answers)

With these changes to your code I get this output:

```
1148.15796128275
```

(You may want to format this number as needed.)

Comment: Ah, your point about the percentage makes sense that completely slipped my mind. Also, those changes still go towards an incorrect value, I reformatted my method to refelct the change but the value is still incorrect. Hmm I think the best thing would be for me to go back to pen and paper and just make sure my equation is right.

Comment: There was an error with the equation in the end, however this assisted me the greatest!

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a guess, but how about using a bit more parentheses in this expression:

```
double monthlyPayment =
 loanAmt * interestRate/
 (1 - 1/Math.pow(1 + interestRate, months));
```

to make sure it's calculated in the desired order